# How to uninstall Viber when apt-get remove fails?

Tags: apt, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall Viber but I can't. This is what happens:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove viber

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package viber needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

How can I uninstall Viber successfully?

Comment: How did you install viber? Whats the output of `where viber`? [Edit] your question with it

Comment: What is the status of `dpkg -s viber | grep -i ^status` ? Try adding the `purge` option. `sudo apt-get remove --purge viber`